# Select 3rd maximum value from table

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table named "salary".

```
  user_id salary
    1          100
    2          200
    3          500
    4          500
    5          500
    6          700
    7          800
    8          700
    9          800
```

I need to find out 3rd highest salary from this table.sometimes more than one records wll be in table. How to write query for that? plesae help me

Comment: As Akam says, see DISTINCT

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you need to get **3d highest salary value** which in your case is `500` you can do

```sql
SELECT salary 
  FROM salary
 GROUP BY salary 
 ORDER BY salary DESC
 LIMIT 2, 1
```

Output:

```
| SALARY |
----------
|    500 |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddel](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ae28a/1)** demo

To get all records where salary equals to 3rd highest

```sql
SELECT * 
  FROM salary
 WHERE salary = 
(
  SELECT salary 
    FROM salary
   GROUP BY salary 
   ORDER BY salary DESC
   LIMIT 2, 1
)
```

Output:

```
| USER_ID | SALARY |
--------------------
|       3 |    500 |
|       4 |    500 |
|       5 |    500 |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddel](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ae28a/2)** demo

Comment: ok limit 3,1 will fetch 3rd maximum salary . I need to get that records . here in example 3 records with "500" salary.  i need to return all the records that have the third maximum salary

Comment: Dear **downvoter** don't be shy; let's hear what is it with your down vote?

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
SELECT * FROM salary ORDER BY salary DESC LIMIT 2,1
```

Comment: Why not upvote the answer already posted, rather than posting a duplicate?

Comment: @BenM - maybe because you both wrote it at nearly the same time?

Comment: Please, see difference in seconds between our answers (24 secs). Even server could not notify me by an alert of a new answer in that short period

Comment: SO gives you a notification that a new answer has been posted. I always like to check what it is before I post mine ;)

Comment: Sorry for that. Now, when my answer was upvoted, I'm not sure what to do - delete it or leave is as it is.

Comment: @Eugene - please leave it as it's superior to the first answer (prior to the edit).

Comment: @Bathsheba Why did you feel the need to edit the answer, then?

Comment: ok limit 3,1 will fetch 3rd maximum salary . I need to get that recorda . here in example 3 records with "500" salary.

Comment: @Ammu, are you saying that you need to return all records that have the third maximum salary?

Comment: yes i need to return all the records that have the third maximum salary

Comment: @Eugene just for the record `LIMIT 3,1` will fetch 4th row not 3d. First argument is an `OFFSET`

Comment: Yes, it is. Like previous answer to mine, I've also been "trapped" by that common mistake. Shame on me, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is also an alternative

```
SELECT distinct salary 
FROM salary
ORDER BY salary DESC
LIMIT 2, 1
```

Selecting all records:

```
select * from salary where salary = (
    SELECT distinct salary 
    FROM salary
    ORDER BY salary DESC
    LIMIT 2, 1
)
```

Comment: but it will fetch one record only